# Licensing fee for BDB (Berkeley DB)

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Does anyone know how much Oracle charges for using BDB (Berkeley Database) in a dual-licensed open-source+commercial application?

While Tokyo Cabinet (http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet) provides a similar key-value DB like BDB, it lacks some features like replication, custom recovery logs and checkpointing which BDB has. Oracle on its part has made it very difficult to determine BDB licensing (we have to go through a sales rep and it is taking way too long).

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that both versions 3 & 4 of BDB were BSD licensed.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/berkeley-db/htdocs/licensing.html

It sounds like a call to your Oracle sales rep is in order unless you abide with the wholly open source path.

Comment: BDB is dual licensed. For open source projects it is free. For closed-sourced/commercial projects Oracle charges a license fee.

Comment: Remember that a company can use BSD-licensed software, modify it to whatever extent they what, closed-source it and require licensing fees if they feel like it.